# Boto CloudSearch Searchable documents count

Tags: python, boto, amazon-cloudsearch

I was wondering how do get the count of Searchable Documents using boto? When I try:

```
import boto.cloudsearch
from boto.cloudsearch.domain import Domain    

conn = boto.cloudsearch.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
domain = Domain(conn, conn.describe_domains()[0])
print domain.num_searchable_docs
```

I get

```
boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 401 Unauthorized
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-02-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>NotAuthorized</Code>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>3a8f8731-137a-11e4-9620-892c28eddd75</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

And `cloudsearch2.domain.Domain` doesn't have the `num_searchable_docs` field

Comment: The 401 response looks like a credential problem.  Are you sure boto is configured to use the correct AWS credentials to access this domain?

Comment: It is, because I don't get any problems when making any other boto calls.

Comment: Do you know why it is hitting "http://cloudsearch.amazonaws.com" rather than a search domain like "https://search-my-domain-kxa44uuymjnqo4o7v9nsnh29ce.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Amazon's CloudSearch [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/getting-domain-info.html), I found out that I had to make the query as `q=matchall&q.parser=structured&size=0`, so with boto it would be as follows.

```
from boto.cloudsearch2.layer2 import Layer2

layer2 = Layer2()
domain = layer2.lookup('my-domain')
search = domain.get_search_service()
results = search.search(q='matchall', parser='structured', size=0)
return results.hits
```